# Having problems with saving the answers to a form in HTML/JavaScript to a .txt file specified by the user

Tags: javascript, html

I am having problems with saving the answers from a form in HTML/JavaScript to a .txt file. As you can see, it will ask for all details and a file name to save the data to, but it will not even do anything even after pressing the submit button. Therefore, I am not 100% sure what is going on, and I may have messed uo bad somewhere in the code. For now, I want to be able to do this using only front end languages and no server side knowledge. Disregard main.php in the form action. I am not 100% sure if this can be done at all without PHP.

Build.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Resumaker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src = "main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<header> 
        <nav>
            <h1> RESUMAKER </h1>
            <ul>
                <li style="float:right"><a class = "active" 
                href="build.html" target="_blank"><span> Build a Resume 
                </span></a></li>
                <li><a href="createaccount.html" target="_blank"><span> 
                Create Account </span></a></li>
                <li><a href="signin.html" target="_blank"><span> Sign in 
                 </span></a></li>
                <li><a href="resources.html" target="_blank"><span> 
                Resources </span></a></li>
                <li><a href="contacts.html" target="_blank"><span> Talk to 
                us </span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

<h1 class = "third"><strong> Build your resume here! </strong></h1>

<h2 class = "fourth"> YOUR PERSONAL INFO </h2>

<form autocomplete="on" method="post" class = "fourth">
    <label for = "first_name"> <b>First name:</b> </label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id = "first_name" 
    placeholder="John" autofocus /><br>
    <label for = "last_name"> <b>Last name:</b> </label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id = "last_name" placeholder="Doe" 
    /><br>
    <label for = "user_email"> <b>Email:</b> </label>
    <input type="email" name="user_email" id = "user_email" 
    placeholder="johndoe@gotham.com" autocomplete="off" /><br>
    <label for = "phone_number"> <b>Phone Number:</b> </label>
    <input name="phone_number" type="number" id = "phone_number" 
     placeholder="(987)-654-3210" /><br>
    <label for = "location"> <b>Location:</b> </label>
    <input type="text" name="location" id = "location" placeholder="Gotham 
    City" autofocus /><br>
    <label for = "linkedin"> <b>LinkedIn:</b> </label>
    <input type="url" name="linkedin" id = "linkedin" autofocus /><br>
    <label for="filename"> <b>Filename</b></label>
    <input type = "text" id="filename" value="" size="40" 
    placeholder="title.md">
    <br/><br/>
    <input onclick="saveFormAsTextFile()" type="button" value = "Make your 
     resume" />
    <input type="reset"><br><br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
function saveFormAsTextFile()

    {
    alert('Hey');
    var textToSave =
      '---\n'+
      'First Name: ' + document.getElementById('first_name').value + '\n'+ 
      'Last Name: ' + document.getElementById('last_name').value + '\n' + 
      'Email: ' + document.getElementById('user_email').value + '\n' +
      'Phone Number: ' + document.getElementById('phone_number').value + 
      '\n' + 
      'Location: ' + '\n- ' + document.getElementById('location').value + 
      '\n' + 
      'LinkedIn: ' + '\n- ' + document.getElementById('linkedin').value + 
      '\n' + 

    var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
    var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("filename").value;

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    downloadLink.click();

    }

function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
```

Main file: Test.html

```
<head>
    <title>Resumaker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>

    <header> 
        <nav>
            <h1 class = "second"> RESUMAKER </h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="build.html" target="_blank"><span> Build Your Resume </span></a></li>
                <li><a href="createaccount.html" target="_blank"><span> Create Account </span></a></li>
                <li><a href="signin.html" target="_blank"><span> Sign in </span></a></li>
                <li><a href="resources.html" target="_blank"><span> Resources </span></a></li>
                <li><a href="contacts.html" target="_blank"><span> Talk To Us </span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: you need to prevent the default behavior of your submit event. And where exactly are you using `destroyClickedElement()`?

Comment: I thought about that. How do I do that? I am completely new to HTML/JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the input type to "button". Setting it to "submit" submits the form without firing the onclick function

## EDITED

I looked further into the code and I found on line 19 an element that doesn't exist

```
document.getElementById('content').value
```

## New Edit

Before

```
var textToSaveAsBlob
```

You should replace the ending "+" with ";"

Comment: I changed it to: <input onclick="saveFormAsTextFile()" type="button" value = "Make your resume" /> but it did not do anything

Comment: can you confirm the saveFormAsTextFile() is actually being fired by consoling a  text or alerting a text

Comment: I added alert('Hey') at the end of function, and filled out the form and submitted using the Make button but it just reset the form and did nothing else.

Comment: I got rid of that but it did not do anything and it still won't print the alert or work as it should.

Comment: Update your post with the new JS CODE

Comment: Updated it just now

Comment: Did that. However, still having the same issue.

Comment: I will make a jsfiddle link

Comment: I updated the code for build.html with all the new changes.

Comment: What do you want me to do on that link?

Comment: I think I updated it. I just pressed the update button on top left.

Comment: How? What did you change? and what does it do now?

Answer (score 0):

(**Edit** : replaced first answer)

Remove `action="main.php"`, it calls something that does not exist

Transform the `type="submit"` into a `type="button"`

Comment: I thought the input type submit with the onclick = "JS Function" took care of that.

Comment: It sort of does, it would in many other cases, but links with a `download` tag can't be activated programmatically (nothing happens when you use `.click()` on them in your javascript)

Comment: (for the record, I am not 100% sure of that)

Comment: Correction, I was wrong, you can `.click()` on `download` links all you want, I am looking further into your code to see what is wrong

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to figure it out as well

Comment: I tried that, but it still does not do anything when I press the button after filling out the form.

Comment: I am using a text editor, I do not have a console to check errors. It seems to save and run but not sure how to troubleshoot. I updated my build.html code with new changes as specified.

Comment: If you are using Chrome use Command+Option+I (Mac) or F12 (windows) to open a console
If you are using Firefox use Command+Option+K (Mac), I don't know for windows

Comment: I see this when I use browser console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
VM89 build.html:43 Uncaught ReferenceError: saveFormAsTextFile is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (VM89 build.html:43)